# mutate value from a column based on a range of values in a different column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tibble` of temperature data from data loggers, and I want to create a new column, preferably using `dplyr::mutate()` or some other `{tidyverse}` solution, within 12 hrs of `NA` values.
One issue is that the time series has gaps that are missing entirely (not just recorded as `NA`), such that approaches absed on row indices do not work. It has to be done using the time range.

How can I set up this `mutate` command so that it returns `TRUE` for any row within 12 hours of a missing temperature, and `FALSE` for temperatures not recorded near `NA` values?

### Reprex

```
library(tibble)
temp.dat<-tibble(temperature=c(4,4.3,4.4,4.4,4.5,4.6,NA,NA,4.4,4.3),
    date.time=c(
    as_datetime("2012-09-29 18:00:00"),as_datetime("2012-09-30 00:00:00"), 
    as_datetime("2012-09-30 06:00:00"),as_datetime("2012-09-30 12:00:00"), 
    as_datetime("2012-09-30 18:00:00"),as_datetime("2012-10-01 00:00:00"), 
    as_datetime("2012-10-01 06:00:00"),as_datetime("2012-10-01 12:00:00"), 
    as_datetime("2012-10-01 18:00:00"),as_datetime("2012-10-02 00:00:00")))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   temperature date.time          
         <dbl> <dttm>             
 1         4   2012-09-29 18:00:00
 2         4.3 2012-09-30 00:00:00
 3         4.4 2012-09-30 06:00:00
 4         4.4 2012-09-30 12:00:00
 5         4.5 2012-09-30 18:00:00
 6         4.6 2012-10-01 00:00:00
 7        NA   2012-10-01 06:00:00
 8        NA   2012-10-01 12:00:00
 9         4.4 2012-10-01 18:00:00
10         4.3 2012-10-02 00:00:00
```

### Desired Output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   temperature date.time           censor
         <dbl> <dttm>              <chr> 
 1         4   2012-09-29 18:00:00 F     
 2         4.3 2012-09-30 00:00:00 F     
 3         4.4 2012-09-30 06:00:00 F     
 4         4.4 2012-09-30 12:00:00 F     
 5         4.5 2012-09-30 18:00:00 T     
 6         4.6 2012-10-01 00:00:00 T     
 7        NA   2012-10-01 06:00:00 T     
 8        NA   2012-10-01 12:00:00 T     
 9         4.4 2012-10-01 18:00:00 T     
10         4.3 2012-10-02 00:00:00 T
```

Example of what I have tried

```
temp.dat%>%mutate(censor=if_else(NA %in% 
temp.dat[match(c(date.time,
        date.time-hours(12),
        date.time+hours(12)), temp.dat$date.time),]$temperature,"T","F"))
```

but that sets the value for `censor` for every observation to `TRUE`. The tricky thing here for me is referencing a value of `temperature` in a range of rows defined by `date.time`.

Comment: "Within 12 hours of NA values" (your description) or "within a 12 hour period symmetric around each NA value" (your code)?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't update that since it didn't work. I'll fix it, but it shouldn't matter what the value is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious to see more concise answers.

Here, I join the data to just the rows missing temperature, where the times in the 2nd table are shifted to a range 12 hours before to 12 hours after.

```
temp.dat |>
  left_join(temp.dat |> 
              filter(is.na(temperature)) |>
              mutate(before = date.time - hours(12),
                     after  = date.time + hours(12),
                     censor = "T", .keep = "none"),
            join_by(closest(date.time >= before), date.time <= after)) |>
  mutate(temperature, date.time, censor = coalesce(censor, "F"), .keep = "none")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   temperature date.time           censor
         <dbl> <dttm>              <chr> 
 1         4   2012-09-29 18:00:00 F     
 2         4.3 2012-09-30 00:00:00 F     
 3         4.4 2012-09-30 06:00:00 F     
 4         4.4 2012-09-30 12:00:00 F     
 5         4.5 2012-09-30 18:00:00 T     
 6         4.6 2012-10-01 00:00:00 T     
 7        NA   2012-10-01 06:00:00 T     
 8        NA   2012-10-01 12:00:00 T     
 9         4.4 2012-10-01 18:00:00 T     
10         4.3 2012-10-02 00:00:00 T
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! 
Since transmute has been superceded, mutate will work with the inclusion of `.keep = "none"`. So the first transmute command would be: `mutate(before = date.time - hours(12),after  = date.time + hours(12),censor = "T",.keep = "none")`

If no one is able to figure out something more concise, I'll mark this as the solution.